Way to convert already imported numbered images into an image sequence in After Effects
In After Effects, is there a way to turn an already imported numbered images (PNG in this case) into a single image sequence, without having to import them again? I already assume it is not possible (with creating regular «compositions» being the closest approach), but still.

I'm not sure whether this is exactly what you're asking, but you can update an image sequence in After Effects after you have imported it. This can be very useful if you're importing a sequence from e.g. Blender:

Render the image sequence in Blender
Import the sequence into AE

Then imagine you need to re-render a few frames within the Blender sequence.

Render only the frames you need to fix in Blender
Go back to After Effects and right-click on your image sequence in the Projects tab.
Click on "Reload Footage".

Your sequence will update, and you can re-render your comp with the new files.
Reading your question again, maybe you mean "I've imported a load of images individually into After Effects, how do I add them to a comp as a sequence? You can do this, but it's neater to import them as an image sequence.  But if you want to make a sequence of the images, I would do this:

Select all the images from the Project tab
Drag them into a new comp (by dragging them on to the "Create a new composition" icon at the bottom of the tab. 
A dialogue box will appear asking the duration for each image. Set it as you want (eg 1 frame).
Go to the menu item Composition-->Composition Settings. Set the comp duration to the correct length for all your frames (eg if you have 25 frames at 1 frame duration each, set your comp duration to 25 frames).
With all the layers still selected in your comp, stagger the layers using a plugin like pt_ShiftLayers

